# How do I verify a method was called exactly once with Moq?

Tags: .net, mocking, moq

How do I verify a method was called exactly once with Moq?  The `Verify()` vs. `Verifable()` thing is really confusing.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You can use `Times.Once()`, or `Times.Exactly(1)`:

```
mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Here are the methods on the [Times](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Times) class:

- `AtLeast` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked times times as minimum.
- `AtLeastOnce` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked one time as minimum.
- `AtMost` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked times time as maximum.
- `AtMostOnce` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked one time as maximum.
- `Between` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked between from and to times.
- `Exactly` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked exactly times times.
- `Never` - Specifies that a mocked method should not be invoked.
- `Once` - Specifies that a mocked method should be invoked exactly one time.

Just remember that they are method calls; I kept getting tripped up, thinking they were properties and forgetting the parentheses.

Comment: so how do you get/setup the mockContext ?

Comment: @Choco I assume that's just his Mock instance. So it was something like `var mockContext = new Mock<IContext>()` to set that up.

Comment: I just wonder how `AtLeast`, `AtMost`, `Between`, or `Exactly` could be viewed as property. I mean, they obv need a parameter to do something.

Comment: If you run the code above, will it verify exactly once, and then fail? as the second verification is more than one? or will it always succeed?

Answer (score 29):

Imagine we are building a calculator with one method for adding 2 integers. Let's further imagine the requirement is that when the add method is called, it calls the print method once. Here is how we would test this:

```
public interface IPrinter
{
    void Print(int answer);
}

public class ConsolePrinter : IPrinter
{
    public void Print(int answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}.", answer);
    }
}

public class Calculator
{
    private IPrinter printer;
    public Calculator(IPrinter printer)
    {
        this.printer = printer;
    }

    public void Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        printer.Print(num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

And here is the actual test with comments within the code for further clarification:

```
[TestClass]
public class CalculatorTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenAddIsCalled__ItShouldCallPrint()
    {
        /* Arrange */
        var iPrinterMock = new Mock<IPrinter>();

        // Let's mock the method so when it is called, we handle it
        iPrinterMock.Setup(x => x.Print(It.IsAny<int>()));

        // Create the calculator and pass the mocked printer to it
        var calculator = new Calculator(iPrinterMock.Object);

        /* Act */
        calculator.Add(1, 1);

        /* Assert */
        // Let's make sure that the calculator's Add method called printer.Print. Here we are making sure it is called once but this is optional
        iPrinterMock.Verify(x => x.Print(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);

        // Or we can be more specific and ensure that Print was called with the correct parameter.
        iPrinterMock.Verify(x => x.Print(3), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

*Note*: By default Moq will stub all the properties and methods as soon as you create a Mock object. So even without calling `Setup`, Moq has already stubbed the methods for `IPrinter` so you can just call `Verify`. However, as a good practice, I always set it up because we may need to enforce the parameters to the method to meet certain expectations, or the return value from the method to meet certain expectations or the number of times it has been called.

Comment: I was calling `Verify`, `Times.Once` without ever calling `Setup`.  I would certainly expect `Verify` to blow up in that case, but it didn't.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 No it will not blow up because by default Moq will stub all the properties and methods as soon as you create a `Mock` object. So even without calling `Setup`, Moq has already stubbed the methods for `IPrinter` so you can just call `Verify`. However, as a good practice, I always set it up because we may need to enforce the parameters to the method or the return value from the method.

Comment: Sorry, that was a terrible explanation.  I called `Times.Exactly(1)` and it _didn't_ fail when the method was in fact called twice.  Only after adding `Setup` for the method in question did it fail correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Test controller may be :

```
  public HttpResponseMessage DeleteCars(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
    {
        Car item = _service.Get(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        _service.Remove(id);
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

And When DeleteCars method called with valid id, then we can verify that, Service remove method called exactly once by this test :

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_WhenInvokedWithValidId_ShouldBeCalledRevomeOnce()
    {
        //arange
        const int carid = 10;
        var car = new Car() { Id = carid, Year = 2001, Model = "TTT", Make = "CAR 1", Price=2000 };
        mockCarService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(car);

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        httpRequestMessage.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = new HttpConfiguration();

        //act
        var result = carController.DeleteCar(httpRequestMessage, vechileId);

        //assert
        mockCarService.Verify(x => x.Remove(carid), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```