# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 2 times: m => m.SaveChanges() , UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Please i m having trouble testing this method .

```
public class EFUrlRepository : IUrlsRepository
{
     public EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
     private Security security = new Security();
     public IQueryable<Url> Urls
     {
        get { return context.Urls; }
     }

     public bool AddUrl(Url url)
     {
          if(url.UrlId == 0)
          {
              context.Urls.Add(url);
              context.SaveChanges();
              url.UrlCode = security.Encrypt(url.UrlId.ToString());
              context.SaveChanges();
              return true;
          }
          return false;
     }
}
```

I am trying to test the addUrl of the class above. I try to implement as explained [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx)

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateUrl_saves_a_url_via_context()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Url>>();
    var mockContext = new Mock<EFDbContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Urls).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var repository = new EFUrlRepository();
    Url url = new Url() 
                     {  
                         UrlCode = "TYUyR", 
                         OriginalUrl = "https://fluentvalidation.com", 
                         IpAddress = "127.0.0.1", 
                         PostedDate = DateTime.Now 
                     };
    repository.context = mockContext.Object;


    repository.AddUrl(url);

    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Url>()), Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
}
```

My test fails and throws the exception mentioned in  the title above. Please What could be the problem. I am suspecting my EFDContext binding but i dont know how to go about it. I am not sure where i go wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You invoke `SaveChanges` twice, but are asserting it will be called once.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Hmm i how do i invoke twice sir ?I invoke here  `mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());`

Comment: oh oh oh Sorry ....OMG , thank you sir. Now i see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the method `AddUrl` you call the method `SaveChanges` twice. 
To verify this behaviour you need to change:

```
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

Into:

```
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

You can read about `Times` options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206193/how-do-i-verify-a-method-was-called-exactly-once-with-moq)

Comment: Is there a way to find out where the 2 invocations happened?

Comment: @OlivérRaisz i don't know about a builtin solution, but you can use a callback and inside saving the stack using `Environment.StackTrace`

Comment: How do I do that, could you elaborate?